# Only add value if value is greater zero in Python of multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have an array like this: `tmp.shape = (128, 64, 64)`

I am counting all zeros along the `128` axis like this:

```
nonzeros = np.count_nonzero(tmp, axis=0) // shape = (64, 64)
```

I have an array `c.shape = (64, 64)`

Now I want to add the values of c to tmp along the 128 axis but only if the values of tmp are > 0:

```
for i in range(tmp.shape[0]):
    axis1 = tmp[i,:,:]
    tmp[i, :, :] += (c / nonzeros) // only if tmp[i, :, :] > 0
```

Is that possible to do in a short way? Or do I have to use multiple loops?
I hope anyone can suggest a solution without another loop

Something like this does not work:

```
tmp[i, tmp > 0.0, tmp > 0.0] += (c / nonzeros)
```

> IndexError: too many indices for array

**LONG VERSION**

```
for i in range(tmp.shape[0]):
    for x in range(tmp.shape[1]):
        for y in range(tmp.shape[2]):
            pixel = tmp[i, x, y]
            if pixel != 0:
                pixel += (c[x,y] / nonzeros[x,y])
```

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was just really busy recently therefore I didn't answer straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are basically adding in broadcasted `c/nonzeros` into tmp array, except at places where the tmp element is zero. So, one approach would be to store the mask of `0s` upfront, add in `c/nonzeros` and finally use the mask to reset `tmp` elements.

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
mask = tmp==0
tmp+= c/nonzeros
tmp[mask] = 0
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
# @DSM's soln
def fast(tmp, c, nonzeros):
    return tmp + np.where(tmp > 0, c/nonzeros, 0)

# Proposed in this post
def fast2(tmp, c, nonzeros):
    mask = tmp==0
    tmp+= c/nonzeros
    tmp[mask] = 0
    return tmp
```

Timings -

```
In [341]: # Setup inputs
     ...: M,N = 128,64
     ...: tmp = np.random.randint(0,10,(M,N,N)).astype(float)
     ...: c = np.random.rand(N,N)*100
     ...: nonzeros = np.count_nonzero(tmp, axis=0)
     ...: 
     ...: # Make copies for testing as input would be edited with the approaches
     ...: tmp1 = tmp.copy()
     ...: tmp2 = tmp.copy()
     ...: 

In [342]: %timeit fast(tmp1, c, nonzeros)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.22 ms per loop

In [343]: %timeit fast2(tmp2, c, nonzeros)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 ms per loop
```

---

**Shorter alternative**

If you are looking for a compact code, here's another using the mask of `non-0s` to do broadcasted element-wise multiplication with `c/nonzeros` and add into `tmp` and thus have a one-liner solution, like so -

```
tmp += (tmp!=0)*(c/nonzeros)
```

**Note:** To avoid division by `0`, we could edit `nonzeros` at its `0s` with anything other than `0`, say `1` and then use the posted approaches, like so -

```
nonzeros = np.where(nonzeros > 0, nonzeros, 1)
```

Comment: it is correct what you said but I receive this: `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide tmp += np.where(tmp > 0, c / nonzeros, 0)` I do not receive this with my method.

Comment: Could you add this to your solution: nonzeros = `np.where(nonzeros > 0, nonzeros, 1)` ? I do not want do edit it, because it is your answer and I do not want to take the credit.

Comment: @thigi Thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.where` and broadcasting.  After fixing your example code (adding to pixel won't modify tmp),

```
def fast(tmp, c, nonzeros):
    return tmp + np.where(tmp > 0, c/nonzeros, 0)
```

gives me

```
In [6]: tmp = np.random.randint(0, 5, (128, 64, 64)).astype(float)
   ...: c = np.random.randint(10, 15, (64, 64)).astype(float)
   ...: nonzeros = np.count_nonzero(tmp, axis=0)
   ...: 

In [7]: %time slow_result = slow(tmp, c, nonzeros)
CPU times: user 488 ms, sys: 16 ms, total: 504 ms
Wall time: 553 ms

In [8]: %time fast_result = fast(tmp, c, nonzeros)
CPU times: user 4 ms, sys: 4 ms, total: 8 ms
Wall time: 16.4 ms

In [9]: np.allclose(slow_result, fast_result)
Out[9]: True
```

Alternatively, you can often replace `np.where` with a multiplication, something like `tmp + (tmp > 0) * (c/nonzeros)`.

Modifying the code to protect against a situation in which an element of nonzeros is zero is left as an exercise for the reader. ;-)